# About Communities- Portal User Error

Tags: open-id-connect

I am using Google Open ID Connect to link up with Communities , I have configured everything as in the documentation ,
but I am getting the below error in the url:
 "Cannot create Portal user without contact"

So anyone please help me , my google registration handler is as follows :

```
  global class GoogleOpenIDConnect implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
    global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    User u = new User();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE id='00e240000011E3g'];
    u.username = data.email;
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    u.timeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Paris';
    u.localesidkey = 'en_GB';
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.languagelocalekey = 'en_US';
    String alias = data.firstName + data.lastName;
    if(alias.length() > 8) {
    alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
   }
    u.alias = alias;
    u.profileId = p.Id;
    return u;
    }


 global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
   User u = new User(id=userId);
   u.email = data.email;
   u.lastName = data.lastName;
   u.firstName = data.firstName;
  update(u);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Users needs a Contact (linked to a valid Contact).
So you have to do something like in the `createUser` method:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = data.lastname);
insert acc;//you can also query an account
Contact cnt = new Contact(FirstName = data.firstname, LastName = data.lastname, AccountId = acc.Id);
insert cnt;//you can create a PersonAccount instead
u.contactid = cnt.Id;
return u;
```

Comment: Quick related note: you can sometimes run into issues with mixed DML. This document is very helpful for explaining it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm

Comment: Sorry, that's why before returning we need to make an "insert u" DML.